# NSPredicateEditor is clearing the value of its NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nspredicateeditor

I'm using NSPredicateEditor in my project. One of my rows has 2 popup buttons and a text field on the right. If I have something typed in the text field, when I select a different menu item from either of the popup buttons then the text in the text field is deleted. That seems to be the default behavior and I don't want that text deleted. I've tried everything I can think of and can't seem to handle this. Any ideas how to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data by using NSUserDefault it will save and load the data (It won't delete your data unless the user does).

Comment: That's a good thought however with NSPredicateEditor you use these things called row templates. You can have multiple rows in the NSPredicateEditor for one row template. As such I do not see how to link the text fields stringValue to a user default. Plus you can't really get the text field from the row template as it's being created, so I can't even programmatically get at the text field... I don't even know which row is making the changes. If you have a concrete example using the NSPredicateEditor please show it because I can't think of a way to do as you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Access the text fields via the row template's `templateViews` property.

This allows you to get the custom values that have been entered into the textfield. Save the value when it changes.

```
class YourCustomRowTemplate : NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate {

    func printTextFieldValues() {
        let templateViews = super.templateViews

        for view in templateViews {
            if let textField = view as? NSTextField {
                let text = textField.stringValue

                print("Text in the texfield is: \(text)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can set the values the same way, by subclassing `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` and overriding the `templateViews` method.